# Custom query showing only one post per page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a map with markers. Code is working otherwise, but it displays only one result from each post.

```php
<?php 
    $the_query_map = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'country', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if($the_query_map->have_posts()) :
    while($the_query_map->have_posts()): $the_query_map->the_post();

    $the_ID = get_the_ID();

    if( have_rows('single_dealer') ):
    while ( have_rows('single_dealer') ) : the_row();

    $get_google_map = get_sub_field('map', $value);
    $marker_description = get_sub_field('description', $value);

    $output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = '<div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$get_google_map['lng'].'">'.
    $marker_description.'</div>';

    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile; endif;


    ?><div class="acf-map"><?php
foreach( $output_map as $key => $map_marker ):
    echo $map_marker['map'];
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```

How can i get my code to display all results of a post instead of one?

Comment: Did you check if more posts are returned at all? You can check that by printing (print_r) the $the_query_map variabele. If not, something might be wrong with your while loop. If more posts are returned, something might be wrong with your query arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put end of the loop `wp_reset_postdata();` .

```
<?php 
    $the_query_map = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'country', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if($the_query_map->have_posts()) :
    while($the_query_map->have_posts()): $the_query_map->the_post();

    $the_ID = get_the_ID();

    if( have_rows('single_dealer') ):
    while ( have_rows('single_dealer') ) : the_row();

    $get_google_map = get_sub_field('map', $value);
    $marker_description = get_sub_field('description', $value);

    $output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = '<div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$get_google_map['lng'].'">'.
    $marker_description.'</div>';

    endwhile; endif;

    endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
endif;


    ?><div class="acf-map"><?php
foreach( $output_map as $key => $map_marker ):
    echo $map_marker['map'];
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking that this would solve the problem, but after trying it didn't still work.